# AntD React: Disable time ranges for specific dates in DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, antd

I am building a car booking application and I am trying to disable some days and times in the DateRangePicker based on selected car's bookings.

I am using [AntD React DateRangePicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-disabled-date) but I cannot disable specific time ranges for specific dates. If I disable a time range it will be disabled in all days. For example if car A is booked for the periods `23.02.2020 13:00 - 25.02.2020 15:00` and `15.03.2020 08:00 - 20.03.2020 17:00` I want to disable the time ranges `13:00 - 24:00 of 23.02.2020`, `00:00 - 15:00 for 25.02.2020`, `08:00 - 24:00 of 15.03.2020` and `00:00 - 17:00 of 20.03.2020`. But there is no such an option in the documentation.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to implement it by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `disabledDate` props to do this

```
const format = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm";
const disabledDates = [
  {
    start: "23.02.2020 13:00",
    end: "25.02.2020 15:00"
  },
  {
    start: "15.03.2020 08:00",
    end: "20.03.2020 17:00"
  }
];

<RangePicker
  onChange={onChange}
  defaultValue={[moment(), moment()]}
  showTime
  disabledDate={current => {
    console.log(current);
    return disabledDates.some(date =>
      current.isBetween(
        moment(date["start"], format),
        moment(date["end"], format)
      )
    );
  }}
/>
```

Exemple: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wiles-zedz6

Exemple with hours: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-booth-nchl2

You can read more about `moment.isBetween` here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: @thelaw ops, sorry, I forgot to fork

Comment: thank you, but it seems that its not working as expected.... for example `start: "23.02.2020 13:00",end: "25.02.2020 15:00"` should be unavailable but in the calendar 23.02.2020 is totally disabled and 25.03.2020 it totally enabled

Comment: @thelaw I have added an exemple with hours too